# Rundeck schedule a job on the first monday of the month

Tags: rundeck, dayofmonth

I would like to a rundeck job on a specific day of the month. Like for example the first Monday of the month.

I have tried to following: 0 10 10 1-7 * MON *, but this gives me the following error:
"day of week or day of the month must be '?'"

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
0 0 0 ? * 2#1 *
```

You can use [this](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html) website to generate Quartz crontabs.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
0 0 12 ? 1/1 MON#1 *
```

You can use http://www.cronmaker.com/ to generate and test your cron expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

0 0 10 ? 1/1 MON#1 *

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).